# How to get dynamic elements in this case using Selenium/Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I try to get the elements that's loaded dynamically to the page after the page has loaded.

Here is the html excluding the scripts last in the html and some other divs before. The comment-div with type="report" is loaded dynamically to the page. I think the site uses Angular or something.

```
<div class="sc-fUKshf bNdPM">
   <div data-testid="comment" type="report" class="sc-cTmXAz cwRvCX">
      <div class="sc-bCwfaz sc-QfGIp gDveND hNwnuN">
         <div class="sc-hepHJq gyIWHj">
            <svg width="28" height="27" viewBox="0 0 28 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-testid="report">
               <g transform="translate(.5)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                  <rect fill="#E3DFF2" width="27" height="27" rx="10.916"></rect>
                  <path d="M16.009 10.89h-.602a2.73 2.73 0 00-2.723 2.916c.077 1.119.132 1.821.167 2.107.039.327.169 1.096.389 2.31a2.205 2.205 0 002.452 1.792 2.713 2.713 0 002.341-2.328c.128-.951.215-1.543.259-1.774.037-.194.162-.754.376-1.68a2.73 2.73 0 00-2.66-3.343zm6.038 4.327l-.343-.1a1.662 1.662 0 00-2.129 1.598c.001.322.003.52.007.595.005.106.037.398.093.877a1.36 1.36 0 001.515 1.192c.828-.1 1.53-.655 1.82-1.437l.172-.465a1.73 1.73 0 00-1.135-2.26zM7.453 6.436l-.565.057a3.411 3.411 0 00-3.038 3.842c.345 2.597.606 4.268.785 5.014.19.79.641 2.285 1.353 4.485a3.063 3.063 0 003.13 2.112 2.29 2.29 0 002.114-2.53c-.265-2.443-.409-4.119-.432-5.028-.02-.767.072-2.217.276-4.35a3.305 3.305 0 00-3.623-3.602z" fill="#8F7FCE"></path>
               </g>
            </svg>
            <div data-testid="activity-title" class="sc-dmiYbj bEyWbu"><span class="sc-jVBfSZ keEVDi">Weekly report</span></div>
         </div>
         <div class="sc-bCwfaz sc-jomqko hGiREx gbkTPQ">
            <div class="sc-bXXDC jSxSkF">28 May 2021</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      Some text
      <div data-testid="comment-reply-button" class="sc-clYhRO dZSmwI">
         <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 21 21.97" width="21" height="22" class="sc-fdnhOL dYoRsn">
            <path d="M19.03 8.35v10.81a1.81 1.81 0 01-1.8 1.81H2.81A1.81 1.81 0 011 19.16V4.74a1.8 1.8 0 011.81-1.8h9" fill="none" stroke="#384a5f" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"></path>
            <path d="M19.64 3.58a1.57 1.57 0 10-2.41-2l-7.21 7.67v2.7l2.7-.9z" fill="none" stroke="#384a5f" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"></path>
         </svg>
         Text
      </div>
      <div class="sc-iArHnM eEOXNH">
         <form data-testid="reply-form">
            <div class="sc-jfkLlK fHByXR"><textarea data-testid="text-area" placeholder="Text" name="replyMessage" id="replyMessage" rows="3" height="auto" class="sc-fcmMJX ldYVmw"></textarea></div>
            <div class="sc-bHCRaJ gPCKhJ"><button data-testid="comment-reply-cancel-button" type="button" class="sc-ckTSus sc-fzJAIQ kiNKGC irzfTA">Text</button><button data-testid="comment-reply-submit-button" type="submit" class="sc-lbVvki hxgvIg">Text</button></div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the python/selenium code:

```
relativeXpathToReportComments = "//div[@type='report']"
    
try: 
    time.sleep(5) #explicit wait in seconds. 
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, relativeXpathToReportComments))) #does not always work?

    comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(relativeXpathToReportComments) #list all elements with comments with type Report
    print("You found the elements for comments:" + comments)
    length = len(comments)
    print (length)
    commentReport = comments[0].get_attribute("innerText").split('\n')[2] #get all the strings inside the element from the first/latest report, in a list with split, then extract only the right comment string (not the title, date etc)
    print("Your last report was:" + commentReport)
except:
    print("could not find/get comments on comment page")
```

90 % of the time I get the result "Could not find/get comments on comment page". It never works on the first run of the code, but when I call a function again that executes the code above it works 5-10 % of the times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `"//div[@type='report']"` locator is not unique, so some other element is caught by Selenium with the expected condition while that element is not clickable.

Comment: I 've tried search for "//div[@type='report']" in Insector tool in Firefox on the previous pages. It only matches this page. The comments is on a dynamic loaded "page". To get to the comments you have to click on a tab that has this html: `<div data-testid="comments-tab-button" class="sc-hUhoqY lkOmmI"><div class="sc-hWZktu dZLBvO"><span class="sc-kLwonV gikjkl">Comments</span></div></div>`

Comment: So you trying to locate the element not on the page where it is presented?

Comment: The element is on the page where it is presented (the html in the OP). Can I try to add a wait somehow to try if that solves the problem?

Comment: Sure you can, you don't have to ask my for that. Also, you can do the following: after the sleep do: `elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@type='report']")` and see the length of `elements` list i.e `length = len(elements)`. if `length = 0` no elements found, if length = 1 there is only 1 such element there but if length is more than 1 your locator is not unique as i mentioned in the beginning

Comment: Elements or "comments" is expected to be a list that captures every comment element that's collected by the relative xpath. So length is expected to be more than 1 if there is more than 1 comment. I tried added a implicit wait. But no matter what seconds I choose, the except error triggers directly (i.e. it does not wait at all). Why is that?

Comment: implicit wait waits for EXISTANCE of element matched by passed locator. So, if there is additional element matching that locator, as we think, there, it will continue to the next code line immediately when it detects that element while it is not clickable. Or, also possible, even if only 1 element matching this locator implicit wait continues to the next code line immediately when the element is found existing while the element is still not completed rendering and it is still not clickable

Comment: That's why I suggested you adding a simple sleep of explicit wait. Using implicit wait is not recommended at all....

Comment: I added an time.sleep(5) (see OP). It now waits but the result it the same " could not find/get comments on comment page". I tried some others explicit waits e.g. visibility_of_element_located. I tried another xpath "//div[2]/div[@type='report']" to see if that makes a difference. Same result.

Comment: It would be much much easier if you could share a link to that page...

Comment: I would if I could but the site requires log in via 2FA and is only accessible by members.